# Existe alguma diferença entre "começar," "iniciar" e "principiar"?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, verbos

Um dos significados de [***Iniciar***](http://www.aulete.com.br/iniciar) é orientar (alguém) na aprendizagem dos fundamentos de uma arte, atividade, etc.. Excluindo este significado, que parece não ser partilhado pelos outros dois verbos, existe alguma diferença ente ***[começar](http://www.aulete.com.br/come%C3%A7ar), iniciar*** e ***[principiar](http://www.aulete.com.br/principiar)***? Por exemplo, as frases seguintes parecem dizer a mesma coisa:

> O autor começa a narrativa com uma descrição do palácio.
>
> O autor inicia a narrativa com uma descrição do palácio.
>
> O autor principia a narrativa com uma descrição do palácio.

A versão com *inicia* não me soa tão bem como as outras. Existem outros contextos em que estes verbos possam introduzir cambiantes diferentes no significado? Ou em que algum deles não seja apropriado?

Comment: Não vejo qual é o problema com "iniciar". Podes também juntar "encetar" à lista.

Comment: Não sei dizer. Talvez seja só falta de exposição minha. Parece-me que *encetar* tem aplicação mais limitada. Mas podes sempre discuti-lo numa resposta tua...

Comment: Principiar não conhecia, iniciar soa-me bem nessa frase. Acho que iniciar é um bocadinho mais formal que começar, pelo menos em Portugal. Principia presumo que seja ainda mais formal. Ou estou enganado?

Comment: @JorgeB. Não estás enganado. Vê as respostas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não são muito diferentes; aliás, teria dificuldade em encontrar também uma diferença entre *começo*, *início* e *princípio*.

#### Registo

*Começar* é o verbo mais comum e é usado em todos os registos. *Iniciar* é mais usado na escrita e registos mais formais e *principiar* só mesmo na escrita.

#### Formas perifrásticas

*Começar* e *principiar* formam perífrases verbais com o gerúndio (esp. Brasil) ou *a + <infinitivo>* (especialmente em Portugal):

> (1) Em 1974, os socialistas **começaram cantando** a «Internacional», **a erguer** o braço (como os romanos e os fascistas) ... mas de «punho cerrado» e, ainda, **a tratar-se** por «camaradas».
> (2) No entanto, o padre de Barroso agachou-se na cova, e **principiou a tirar** seixos sarapintados de manchas amarelas, e laminados sobrepostamente.

Embora aqui o contexto não deixe dúvidas, frases deste género são ambíguas porque podemos interpretar "cantando" e "a tirar" com função adverbial. Com *iniciar* essa é a única interpretação possível (não forma perífrase verbal):

> (3) A Bolsa de Nova Iorque teve uma semana de tendência mista, embora tenha **iniciado a perder** com alguma força.
> (4) No quarto «set», ambos os tenistas aguentaram o serviço até ao nono jogo, que Sampras **iniciou servindo** um ás, que o árbitro julgou como sendo fora.

Também se pode dizer *começar/principiar por + <infinito>*, mas não *iniciar por + <infinito>*.

#### *Iniciar* como verbo intransitivo

O Aulete Digital mostra este exemplo:

> (5) A semana *iniciou* com boas notícias.

Este uso é incomum. Geralmente usar-se-ia *iniciar* pronominalmente: *iniciou-se*. *Começar* e *principiar* não se podem usar usar pronominalmente.

#### Usos específicos de *começar*

*Começar*, em certos usos intransitivos e especialmente com *por*, parece dificilmente substituível por *iniciar* e *principiar*:

> (6) Comecemos pelo primeiro.
> (7) Começou pelo degrau de baixo.
> (8) Começámos em último, mas chegámos à frente.
> (9) As casas aqui começam nos 500 mil euros.

O Aulete Digital [dá estas definições e exemplos](http://www.aulete.com.br/come%C3%A7ar):

> 3. Iniciar (de determinada maneira). [tp. : *A música começou altíssima*.]
> 4. Fazer sua estreia em algo, ou sua primeira experiência ou tentativa. [int.: *A empresária começou vendendo jóias.*]
> 5. Fazer (algo) como início de ação, atividade, atuação etc. [tr. + por : *Subiu ao palco para sua apresentação, e começou por contar uma anedota.*]

#### Usos específicos de *iniciar*

*Iniciar* significa também:

- Ensinar ou introduzir alguém ou a si mesmo em alguma disciplina, grupo, comportamento, etc.: *David Sylvian iniciou-o nos prazeres contemplativos de «Flight & Premonition» e «Flux and mutability».* ([significados 2 e 3](http://www.aulete.com.br/iniciar) do Aulete Digital)
- Em informática, como sinónimo de *arrancar* (um programa, um computador) (significado 5 do Aulete); parece-me que como sinónimo de *inicializar* (significado 4 do Aulete) é raro o uso

Comment: Boa resposta exaustiva. O *iniciar* intransitivo também me soa estranho, como no teu exemplo (3) e implicitamente no 3 do Aulete (música). Nos teus exemplos (6) a (8) e Aulete 4 e 5, dá-me a ideia que se começa alguma coisa (discussão, trabalho) ou a fazer alguma coisa, e eu estaria inclinado a aceitar *principiar* também, talvez com outra proposição: *principiou com uma anedota*.

Answer (score 1):

Não, no Brasil, essas 3 palavras - iniciar, começar e principiar - são sinônimas (mesmo significado). Porém, dependendo da frase, há melhores opções:

- Vamos INICIAR a prova.
- Agora está na hora de "COMEÇAR" a receita (comida)

  Já PRINCIPIAR não é muito utilizado como verbo. Usa-se mais "PRINCÍPIO" e se refere-se a algo mais antigo ou alguma história/estória. Algo até mais social, para dar uma ênfase mais bonita ao artigo/escrito.
- À PRINCÍPIO, não havia jogos eletrônicos (No INÍCIO/começo não havia jogos eletrônicos).
- No PRINCÍPIO do século XV...

Digamos que "INICIAR" e "COMEÇAR" podem ser consideradas palavras mais populares. E, como todos os sinônimos, às vezes há a necessidade de repetir o significado, mas fica algo "sujo" usar a mesma palavra.

- Vamos INICIAR a receita. INICIAREMOS colocando a farinha...  (fica "feio"/"sujo"
- Vamos INICIAR a receita. COMEÇAREMOS colocando a farinha...

Answer (score 1):

'A principal diferença no comportamento sintáctico destes dois verbos é a seguinte:

O verbo começar é usado como auxiliar aspectual, regendo as preposições a ou por:

(1) «O menino começou a gritar.»

(2) «A cozinheira começou por fazer a sobremesa.»

Ou, no português Brasil, usando o gerúndio:

(3) «O menino começou gritando.»

(4) «A cozinheira começou fazendo a sobremesa.»

O verbo iniciar é usado como bitransitivo e pronominal:

(5) «Os pais iniciaram o filho no desporto aos 5 anos.»

(6) «O João iniciou-se na política com 18 anos.»

Sandra Duarte Tavares '

in Ciberdúvidas da Língua Portuguesa, https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-diferenca-no-uso-dos-verbos-comecar-e-iniciar/25492 [consultado em 24-08-2021]

Comment: Boas-vindas e obrigado por sua contribuição! Uma pequena retificação que eu faria é que também se usa o exemplo (1) no Brasil, e a alternativa proposta, (3), na verdade soa estranha aos meus ouvidos — inclusive com significado distinto, não de "ele passou a gritar", mas de "ele começou [algo] com um grito".

Answer (score 0):

Não parece haver diferença de significado entre os três verbos quando transitivos. Aos meus ouvidos de ultramar "principia" é unusual e eu muito provavelmente não usaria.  Essa parece ser a única diferença que percebo. "Começa" e "inicia" soam bem.  Por ordem decrescente, eu usaria:

- O autor **começa** a narrativa com uma descrição do palácio.
- O autor **dá inicio** a narrativa com uma descrição do palácio.
- O autor **inicia** a narrativa com uma descrição do palácio.